# Как конкретно работает команда repe scasb?

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Меня интересует "механика". Какие регистры изменяются, по каким адресам производится обращение к памяти.

Comment: http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/SCASB  http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/REP

Answer (score 3):

`SCASB` сравнивает `AL` с байтом, по адресу из `RDI` (или `ES:EDI` в 32-битном режиме) и выставляет флаги (`OF`, `SF`, `ZF`, `AF`, `PF` и `CF`). Затем `RDI` увеличивается или уменьшается на 1, в зависимости от флага `DF`. Префикс `REPE` образует цикл, заставляя инструкцию выполняться повторно пока `RCX` (на каждой итерации его значение уменьшается на 1) не станет равен 0 или не будет сброшен флаг `ZF`.